# Try to install gnome shell in saucy

Tags: gnome, 13.10, dependencies

I try to install gnome-shell in saucy but it won't work.
And I installed the 13.10 in parallels desktop on a Mac.

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gnome-shell : Depends: gir1.2-clutter-1.0 (>= 1.11.11) but it is not installable
               Depends: gir1.2-mutter-3.0 (>= 3.8.3) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: gir1.2-telepathyglib-0.12 but it is not installable
               Depends: gir1.2-accountsservice-1.0 but it is not installable
               Depends: gir1.2-gcr-3 (>= 3.7.5) but it is not installable
               Depends: gir1.2-gkbd-3.0 but it is not installable
               Depends: gir1.2-gnomedesktop-3.0 (>= 3.7.90) but it is not installable
               Depends: gir1.2-nmgtk-1.0 but it is not installable
               Depends: gir1.2-polkit-1.0 but it is not installable
               Depends: gir1.2-telepathylogger-0.2 (>= 0.8.0) but it is not installable
               Depends: gir1.2-upowerglib-1.0 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Try using aptitude instead of apt-get, and using aptitude install -f

Comment: Visit: http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies
Trying this should fix your problem.

Comment: @simbadub23 Thank you for helping me to fix the problem. It does help:)

Comment: Glad I could help.

Comment: Try wiyh `sudo apt-get install gnome-shell gir1.2-clutter-1.0 gir1.2-accountsservice-1.0 gir1.2-gcr-3 gir1.2-gkbd-3.0 gir1.2-gnomedesktop-3.0 gir1.2-telepathyglib-0.12 gir1.2-mutter-3.0 gir1.2-nmgtk-1.0 gir1.2-polkit-1.0 gir1.2-telepathylogger-0.2 gir1.2-upowerglib-1.0`

Answer (score 1):

**Try to install the latest version by adding the repository: `ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3`**

Follow these simple steps:

- Open terminal and execute these commands:

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
  sudo apt-get -f update
  sudo apt-get install gnome-shell ubuntu-gnome-desktop
  ```
- If all goes well, logout and chose the **gnome** from the list.

  Note: While installing if it still says not able to install libraries or some other packages then consider to add one more repository:

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging && sudo apt-get -f update
  ```

  then try to install again.

If you get any problem and you want to remove the packages and repository then you can use ppa-purge to safely remove it.

- Install `ppa-purge`:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
  ```
- Then remove packages:

  ```
  sudo ppa-purge ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
  sudo ppa-purge ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging
  sudo apt-get -f update
  sudo apt-get remove gnome-shell ubuntu-gnome-desktop
  ```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I try to install latest version of gnome.But it does not work. Occasionally I change the ubuntu software center's download mirrors, and it works, I install gnome. But still do not know what causes this problem.